# Sending and storing text over endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

This is a very simple question: what method would you advise to send text, not formatted, simple text with possible carriage returns, over Endpoints (or google's Proto-RPC library), and store it?

Obviously, the best way to store it is to user the `ndb.TextProperty`, but how "flexible" is the `messages.StringField` RPC field? Should i rather use the `messages.ByteField` ?

If you know anything about length limitations, encoding and such, go ahead and share your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should serialize it to `base64` and `BytesField` will do this by default.

This both reduces the need to deal with exotic characters (e.g. carriage return) and reduces the size of the payload.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess i use python's base64.decode before storing the stirng, right?

Comment: Server side you just set the property as a `str` object and the library handles it. Client side you'll need custom code but it's a very common task.

Comment: Ok i'll try this out and see